# issue making navigation float left

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, nav

I have a feedback panel but the problem is that when you click on it the navigation overrides some contents of the feedback panel.

As you can see in the image above the email input field is blocked.

**Question**

What I want to do is that when a user clicks on the feedback, the `<nav>` will float to the left so that the user can enter what they want and then they click on `feedback` again and the `nav` returns back to `center`.

**nav bar css**

```
nav{
text-align:center;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="panel">
    <h3>Sliding Panel</h3>
    <p>Here's our sliding panel/drawer made using jQuery with the toggle function and some CSS3 for the rounded corners</p>

    <p>This panel is placed on the right instead of on the left. This could be particularly useful if, <a href="http://spyrestudios.com" title="SpyreStudios">like me</a>, you have a left-aligned website layout.</p>



<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just set the `z-index` on the feedback panel to 50 (or more if it comes before the nav in the DOM). That way it will appear above the nav and you don't have to worry about moving the nav out of the way.

Otherwise, if you really want to move the nav out of the way when the feedback panel is shown, you could do something like this:

```
$('.feedback-button').click(function(){
    $('nav').toggleClass('moved');
   /* whatever else you do when the feedback button is clicked */
});
```

Which would toggle a "moved" class on the nav element whenever the feedback button is clicked. This is assuming the existance of a feedback button of some sort with the class "feedback-button".

Then you can set some css like this:

```
nav.moved {
  -webkit-transform:translate(-100px,0);
  transform:translate(-100px,0);
}
```

Which would move the nav left by 100 pixels when the moved class is set.

If you want it to animate, you could add a transition to the nav element as well.

```
nav {
  -webkit-transition:transform 1s ease-in-out;
  transition:transform 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: the thing with this is that it already move the `nav` out of the way before the feedback button is clicked. which it should. The feedback button need to be clicked first

Comment: @Emily You mustn't include a "moved" class on the nav element in the original html. The `toggleClass` call will add it for you.

Comment: This is how it is `<nav>` css `nav.moved{
transform:translate(-100px,0);
text-align:center;
}`

Comment: The reason why i do not want the nav to be fix a float left is because the feedback panel is only on the home page.

Comment: The nav will only move left when the "moved" class is set. And the "moved" class will only be set when the feedback button is pressed. If there is no feedback panel on the home page then assumedly the button can never be pressed so the nav will never be moved. If I've misunderstood what your markup looks like, maybe include a jsfiddle link with enough markup to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I fixed it thanks to your help... the answer is below. Thanks again

Comment: Oh ok. I see you just wanted the nav floated left. I thought you wanted it moved a few pixels. I'm glad you worked it out.

Answer (score 0):

**javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".trigger").click(function(){
        $(".panel").toggle("fast");
        $('nav').toggleClass('moved');
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

**css**

```
.moved{
float:left;
}
```